# Variable PHP $_POST[] no obtiene la variable pasada de un formulario HTML con action="POST"

Tags: php

De este código de formulario, no me coge un simple echo de **POST** Nombres

```
<form name="form" action="darAltaCliente.php"  action="POST">
        <input name="nombre" type="text"placeholder="Nombres" ></br></br>
        <input name="Apellidos" type="text"placeholder="Apellidos"></br></br>
        <input name="DNI" type="text"placeholder="DNI"></br></br>
        <input name="Número  de Personas" type="number"placeholder="Número  de Personas"></br></br>
        <input name="Localidad de Origen" type="text"placeholder="Localidad de Origen"></br></br>
        <input name="Tarjeta de crédito" type="number"placeholder="Tarjeta de crédito"></br></br>
         <!-- Borrar los valores -->
  <label for="Borrar">¿Quieres resetear?</label>
  <input type="reset" value="Borrar">

  <!-- Recoger los datos -->
  <label for="Enviar">Enviar</label>
  <input type="submit" name="Enviar">
    </form>
```

y este sería el código de PHP a darAltaCliente.php

```
<?php
echo $_POST["nombre"]; 
?>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tu declaración del formulario esta mal hecha.

Actualmente tienes

```
<form name="form" action="darAltaCliente.php"  action="POST">
```

Debería ser:

```
<form name="form" action="darAltaCliente.php" method="POST">
```

el atributo para el tipo de petición es **method**, no **action**